How do I fullscreen Chrome but not the tabs?
I've had this issue lately where whenever I fullscreen the Chrome window. All the tabs become full-screened instead of the window being full-screened and the tab not being full-screened.
I've tried Cmd+Ctrl+F, pressing/holding Esc when full-screened, and the green button to the top left and nothing's worked so far.
The issue started when I was going to play a game on a site, so I full-screened it, and it started there. I tried returning to that website and doing what I did that made it go fullscreen, but it still wouldn't work. Any solutions?
